# Why does leaving off a semicolon break this code?

Tags: javascript

Or put another way, why does semicolon insertion fail, leaving the code below broken.

```
function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log("bar");
} // <------------ missing semicolon

(function () {
    Foo.prototype.la = function () {
        console.log("la");
    };
})();
```

Why is the JavaScript parsing engine trying to combine `Foo.prototype.bar = function () {` with what's in my closure?  Is there anything I could put in that closure that would make this sensible?

I'm not advocating leaving off semicolons with the expectation that semicolon insertion will save you; I'm just wondering why (a more useful version of) the above code broke when I accidentally left one off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like this...

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function () { // <-- 1. function
    console.log("bar");
}(function () {    // <-- 2. call the 1. function, passing a function argument
    Foo.prototype.la = function () {
        console.log("la");
    };
})();  // <-- 3. tries to invoke the return value of the 1. function, 
       //            but "undefined" was returned.
```

I don't like using `()` for IIFE. I prefer other operators.

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log("bar");
}

void function () {
    Foo.prototype.la = function () {
        console.log("la");
    };
}();
```

---

If we go back to the original, and have the first function return a function, you'll see that one invoked.

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function () { // <-- 1. function

    console.log("bar");
    return function() { alert('INVOKED'); }; // 2. return a function

}(function () {    // <-- 3. call the 1. function, passing a function argument
    Foo.prototype.la = function () {
        console.log("la");
    };
})();  // <-- 4. tries to invoke the return value of the 1. function,
       //         which will now call the returned function with the "alert()"
```

---

*Updated to use a unary operator as suggested by [@Lasse Reichstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360206/lasse-reichstein), as a binary operator will still evaluate its left and right operands, and return the result, which will be used for the assignment.*

Comment: Yep - so now bar is assigned not that function, but the result of that function when invoked with what's in those parens.  Thank you

Comment: HEH - I honestly thought I was the only person who preferred `+function()` ... I thought the only other people who did that were minifiers :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: There's a few of us out there. :) I actually prefer `void` if I'm not concerned about too many characters. Seems to stand out more.

Comment: Using '+' instead doesn't help this problem - it just tries to add the two functions - hilarity ensues. Instead you can use '!' or another unary operator (e.g., 'void' as also suggested).

Comment: @LasseReichstein: Heh, good catch! You're right, a unary operator should be used. I'll update.

Answer (score 4):

Because it sees the ( on the line below and takes it to mean you want to *call* the above (using the below function as an argument).