# Can someone explain this javascript pattern used in the Twitter Bootstrap plugins to me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking at the jQuery plugins for [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js) and saw that they were all defined using a pattern like this:

```
!function($) {
  // code here

  // plugin definition here

} ( window.jQuery || window.ender);
```

This looks like a variation of the immediately executing anonymous function (anonymous closure):

```
(function($) {
  // code here

}(jQuery));
```

Can someone explain what the Bootstrap variation does and why? Is this a better way to write an anonymous closure?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the only difference is that it saves you a character... Oh, and makes the pattern _obscure_.

Comment: @Jordão: Avoiding the `()` helps avoid bugs [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944398/why-does-leaving-off-a-semicolon-break-this-code)

Comment: @am not i am: thanks for pointing that out. I'd still not use this idiom though, as it's not the proper way to fix that kind of bug.

Comment: @Jordão: I wouldn't call it an improper fix. Irrespective of the bug, I still don't use `()` to create an IIFE. The bug is a combination of JS only having function scope, having ASI, and overloading the `()` syntax. It's up to the individual developer as to how they want to deal with it. Inserting a semi-colon is one option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//  |---1. makes the function as part of an expression 
//  |                             so it can be immediately invoked
//  v
    !function($) {
//            ^
//            |___4. references what was passed, window.jQuery or window.ender

      // code here

      // plugin definition here

    } ( window.jQuery || window.ender); // <---2. immediately invoke the function 
//         ^                ^
//         |________________|_______3. pass window.jQuery if it exists, 
//                                                      otherwise window.ender
```

Comment: Nice answer - thanks! So it looks like it really is another way of doing the same thing with the benefit of preventing bugs when the code is combined?

Comment: @ɹǝʇǝd: Yeah, if you forget a semicolon before this, the `()` may be interpreted as attempting to call a function.

Comment: What is `window.ender`? In which cases is it populated? I couldn't find much information, except for Bootstrap code of course.

Comment: @DanAbramov: I honestly don't know. It certainly isn't any standard property of `window`.

Comment: Ender is an open module JavaScript framework. See http://ender.no.de/ for more information.

Comment: What's the difference between prefixing with an "!" or not?

Comment: @mike: The concern is that the syntax is interpreted such that the `function` keyword is not seen as *function declaration* syntax, but rather as an anonymous function that is part of an expression. This allows the immediate invocation. Almost any operator can be used to accomplish this. The *logical not* operator is just one. Some people wrap the entire function in `()`, but bugs can crop up with this approach. If you remove the `!`, and don't use anything else to make it a function expression, then you'll get a *SyntaxError* because it'll be seen as a declaration with its *name* missing.

Comment: One downside of such approach is that it doesn't validate in JSHint or JSLint.